# WebUrl property in Microsoft Graph does not match the URL in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-sdks

We have a SharePoint site with a given URL:

https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/US01/tech/bleep/ohio

I have gotten the siteID for this site, and when I get the drive.root.children for the site using Microsoft Graph, I can look at the properties of one of the items under "currentPage" and the WebUrl property does not match the URL in SharePoint.The WebUrl property shows:

https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/US01/SharedDocuments

As the path instead of the one I got the siteID for. If I go to the root site (https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/US01/) and try to get the site ID for that one, I get an access denied message.

I've done this on another site and everything worked okay. The URLS matched and I was able to traverse the library. For this one, I don't understand what is happening.

Does anyone know why the WebUrl property would not match the SharePoint URL?

Answer (score 0):

So, just in case anyone else is trying to figure this out, here's the answer.

SiteID refers to a site collection.
WebID refers to a subsite ID.

This means that in my original post, the ID I was getting back was indeed correct. To get a subsite ID (webID), you need to add the following to the end of the SharePoint URL:

/_api/web/id

Once you have both ID's, you can use a Microsoft Graph method to get the drives (libraries) from your subsite:

```
 var libDrives = await _graphServiceClient.Sites[siteID].Sites[subSiteID].Drives.Request().GetAsync();
```

And there you have it!